# How to pass parameter to web method from prototype

Tags: javascript, ajax, prototypejs

I want to pass parameter to webmethod but there is no action. I delete parameters from method and prototype ajax request and everything is ok but when I want to use parameter it doesn't work. Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.1.0/prototype.js"></script>
<script>

    var xRequest = new Ajax.Request('PrototypeTest.aspx/Test', {
        method: 'post',
        parameters: { "id": 'asdf' },
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        onSuccess: function (val) {
            var brands = val.responseText.evalJSON().d.evalJSON();
            brands.each(function (brand) {
                alert(brand.Name);
            });
        },
        onerror: function (val) {
            debugger;
            alert('hata');

        }
    });
</script>

 [WebMethod]
    public static string Test(string id)
    {
        List<brand> brands = new List<brand>();
        brands.Add(new brand()
            {
                Name = "BMW",
                IsActive = true
            });

        var json = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        return json.Serialize(brands);
    }
```

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it is correct way but it solved my problem:

```
 Ajax.Request('PrototypeTest.aspx/Test?prod=1', {`...
```

I passed parameters as query string.

Comment: This is one of the ways - the example code above will work too - but the parameters will be passed as POST parameters instead of GET. If you change `'method':'post'` to `'method':'get'` you would get the same result